# What is the best method for an adaptive file path in python? e.g. using pd.read_csv()

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write a script which allows everyone in my remote team to run scripts from our shared dropbox. However, I am struggling with paths when reading csv's.

```css
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Joe\\Dropbox........')
```

For the above, I need to be able to automatically replace the user (in this case Joe) with whoever is trying to run the script. I have done this before, but its always been clunky, so was wondering if someone have a clean method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Would setting up a script argument work for you?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

```
import argparse

# Creating the parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "some decription")

# Adding some argument
parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", help = "path/to/csv", required = True)

# Parsing the arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

# Reading the csv
df = pd.read_csv(args.path)
```

Then to run the script:

```
python my_script.py -p path/to/my/csv
```